# Facet Queries Slow During Replication in solr 6.4.2

Tags: performance, solr, lucene, replication

We have a solr core in which we replicate data every 30 minutes.
I am facing an issue regarding searcher .
Every time Replication happens the simple queries are executed as expected but the facet queries take a very long time in execution .
I have enabled cold searcher setting.

Sample facet queries:

2017-12-22 04:40:25.801 INFO  (qtp834133664-539) [   x:cdaapp] o.a.s.c.S.Request [cdaapp]  webapp=/solr path=/select params={q=sJID:8664459&facet.field=sS&facet.field=sHQLID&facet.field=sFCLID&facet.field=sASIDN&facet.field=sNEx&qt=edismax&facet.mincount=1&rows=0&facet=on&wt=json} hits=15 status=0 QTime=14651

2017-12-22 04:40:25.823 INFO  (qtp834133664-569) [   x:cdaapp] o.a.s.c.S.Request [cdaapp]  webapp=/solr path=/select params={q=sJID:8641232&facet.field=sS&facet.field=sHQLID&facet.field=sFCLID&facet.field=sASIDN&facet.field=sNEx&qt=edismax&facet.mincount=1&rows=0&facet=on&wt=json} hits=13 status=0 QTime=11226

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest setting facet method to enum.

```
facet.method=enum
```

This parameter indicates what type of algorithm/method to use when faceting a field.

> **enum**  - Enumerates all terms in a field, calculating the set
>   intersection of documents that match the term with documents that
>   match the query. This was the default (and only) method for faceting
>   multi-valued fields prior to Solr 1.4.
>
> **fc** (stands for Field Cache) The facet counts are calculated by
>   iterating over documents that match the query and summing the terms
>   that appear in each document. This was the default method for single
>   valued fields prior to Solr 1.4.
>
> **fcs** (stands for Field Cache per Segment) works the same as fc except
>   the underlying cache data structure is built for each segment of the
>   index individually